# MATLAB Neural Network Generalisation

Tags: matlab, networking, speech, mfcc

I'm currently working on a neural network for speech recognition in MATLAB, and have extracted MFCCs for classification purposes. Currently there are 500 features for each 1-second speech clip, and there are five different classes (i.e. five different words)

I am using two different batches of speech clips: One is 500 files that I am using to train the neural network (as well as validation/testing as per the nprtool's usual computations). The other is made up of 250 files and is purely for testing purposes. Both batches were generated in one go.

Using the first batch, I am able to obtain near-perfect training/validation/testing accuracy (95-100%). However, when I try testing with the second batch (i.e. the separate 250 files), accuracy drops down to 20%. As there are five classes, this initially lead me to think that the neural network is simply picking classes at random. However, looking at the confusion matrix, it seems that the first class is being recognised with 95-100% accuracy - however the other voice files are being completely misclassified.

My first thought is that overfitting has occurred somehow. I'm aware that MapMiniMax function is used by the nprtool for normalisation purposes - could this be destroying the generalisation properties of the neural network? Or is there another step in between the training and testing that I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The step you are missing is before training and testing. It's called "theory". Without understanding how speech recognition work it's hard to advance in it. For recognition of time series you need to use time-scaling NNs like recurrent NNs or NNs combined with HMM. You can use toolkit specifically designed for speech recognition with NN like [Kaldi](http://kaldi.sourceforge.net).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but to be completely honest do you really think this is the issue here? As I mentioned in the question I have achieved fairly high accuracy using the vanilla neural network approach. My problem is that I cannot replicate this accuracy with a separate batch of test data. Plus, with this test data, one of the classes seems to be very well-recognised, while the others are not. As such, I can't help but feel there's a normalisation issue more than anything else. Of course, Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It's not me thinking that your approach is not going to work, it is the theory that says so.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how you can say that according to theory, my approach is not going to work when I have already proven that to a certain extent, it does.